# AirPrint - Make number of copies default to 2 and not just 1 copy

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, airprint

When I open the print options using AirPrint, I want to make it default to 2 copies and not just 1 copy.

Couldn't find any methods that could change the number of copies. Wondering if anyone has any ideas if this is possible since it seems that this printing option is pretty limited.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?  My first thought would be to send two identical items to be printed via `printingItems` and hide the number of copies option

Comment: The code that I'm using is from this website https://iosrider.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/iphoneipad-airprinting-tutorial/ 

I tried sending two `printingItem` to the `printController` but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my own solution. Basically under the UIPrintInteraction Controller there is a method called `printItems`. What I did is make an `NSArray` and put two copies of the object I wanted to print and used that method instead of `printItem`.

However, since my application used the `printFormatter` I was unable to use this method since in the IOS developer documentation it says 
"If you set this property (`printFormatter`), UIPrintInteractionController sets the `printingItems`, `printingItem`, and `printPageRenderer` properties to `nil`. (Only one of these properties can be set for a print job.)"

So what I did was just doubled the html page I was formatting and I trusted that the formatting was correct for it to print two pages.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to add the same `printFormatter` to page 1 and page 2 in a `printPageRenderer`.